# Leaflet mobile location ignored

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm using Leaflet (and mapbox) to display an overview of some geojson points on a map.
I was experimenting with the 'locate' feature to show a marker on the current position of the user.

The problem is on the mobile version the location is being ignored, On my phone it's showing all the geojson data

**but it's not showing the marker with my current location on mobile, which is working on the desktop version**.. 
Any ideas?

Here's the code i'm using, it's fairly simple

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mymap.h0fk0koa');
var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer(geojson).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());

map.locate({
    setView: true,
    watch: true,
    maxZoom: 16
});

function onLocationFound(e) {
    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [HTML5 geolocation demo](http://html5demos.com/geo) on your desktop browser and your phone. It's likely that your phone is configured never to share its location via HTML5, and you just need to adjust some privacy settings in order to permit the location API.

Comment: It's stuck on 'checking'. It asked me once if i wanted to allow it to see my location.. Now it's not asking anymore, even after cache erase or incognito mode.. strange!

My location settings are set to enable ( using android )

Answer (score 0):

On the Samsung Galaxy S3, you have to open your browser, hit the menu button at the bottom left of the phone, and choose Settings > Privacy and Security > Clear Location Access. This resets all location permissions you have given. Now your phone will again ask you if you want to share your location...